# How to format date and time in Dygraphs legend according to user locale

Tags: javascript, jquery, dygraphs

I have a graph that displays a device's power output over time and I'd like to format the legend so that it displays the timestamps in the style of where the current user is (for example, in the US it would show `MM/DD/YY h:m:s am/pm`, and in EU would show `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`, etc.).

Currently, it's set at default, as follows:

[image]

I pass in a JS `Date()` object for the x-axis and I've found that you can [modify the x-axis labels](http://dygraphs.com/tests/x-axis-formatter.html), but I can't find any info on changing the format of the legend when hovering over the graph.

Comment: I don't know the Dygraphs library. If you have the ability to pass in a string, you could use locale-formatted dates, but unfortunately `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString` isn't supported on every browser, so you'll have to use a polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat#Polyfill

Comment: I looked at Date.toLocaleString() and it is something that I'd want to use, especially since I already have the Date() objects inside Dygraphs. The issue is telling Dygraphs to use toLocaleString(), and I can't find anywhere in their docs on how to do this. I found [this part](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#xValueFormatter), but without usage examples it's not as useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've discovered the [`axisLabelFormatter`](http://www.dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelFormatter) option, which lets you control formatting of labels on the x-axis.

To control formatting of labels in the legend, you need to use [`valueFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueFormatter)

```
g = new Dygraph(div, data,
    axes: {
        x: {
            axisLabelFormatter: function (d, gran) {
                return d.toLocaleDateString();
            },
            valueFormatter: function (ms) {
                return new Date(ms).toLocaleDateString();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/6836/) for a fully-worked example. Is it odd that one formatter function takes a Date whereas the other takes millis since epoch? Yes. Unfortunately, it's an inconsistency we're stuck with.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!