# Localizing date on shiny Dygraphs

Tags: r, date, shiny, localization, dygraphs

I've searched a little bit and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174139/152016

But I don't know how to apply these settings on a shiny dygraph.

I would really like to see localized date formats both on x axis and in the graph label.

Just for curiosity data (it really doesn't matter), here's specific code:

```
xtsdata <- tbl_xts(dados %>% filter(localidade%in%dados$localidade), cols_to_xts = "totalCases", spread_by = "localidade")

dygraph(xtsdata, xlab='Dia', ylab='Casos (acumulado)', main="Gráfico temporal") %>%
      dyRangeSelector() %>%
      dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 3, 
      highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.8,
      highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 2)) %>%
      dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Set2")) %>%
      dyLegend(show = "follow")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than expected, the only mislead was that both properties belong to x axis formatting.

Just add:

```
dyAxis("x", axisLabelFormatter = 'function(d) { return moment(d).format("DD/MMM");}', valueFormatter = 'function(ms) { return moment(ms).format("DD[ de ]MMMM[ de ]YYYY"); }')
```

(For localization I've decided to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/))